# how can I get the exactly right size screen emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm working with flutter in Android Studio in windows.

I set the screen size 768*1024(ipad mini size) when I create my virtual devices in android studio, but I find the height is smaller than expected. Actually when I call function window.physicalSize it shows that the size is 768*796.

I have gotten the fact that the function only shows the size of the screen that flutter can render.(So the hidden part is about what? bottom navigation bar,including three buttons, back, home, and the other one, or something else, I'm not sure.)

So, the question is how can I get exact size screen I want(768*1024)?

Comment: I seems to find a solution. I remove the bottom bar and call the function windows.physicalSize again, then it shows the right size I want. Just in .android/avd/virtual-device.avd/config.ini,  modify hw.mainKeys=yes and
hw.keyboard=yes then it works.